Can a witness at Kiddushin have committed _serious_ crimes, if no one knows?
See Can a witness at Kiddushin have had committed inconsequential crimes?, and Can somone admit to being a invalid witness?. I'd like to expand the question. Say there's an observant Jew who unfortunately has not been that successful in his observance. He believes in the Torah, wants to keep it, but has failed on some serious aveiros, and has not been able to really do teshuvah on them; he knows that so far he hasn't been able to rule them out in the future. He's not a mumar, hasn't given up on them at all, doesn't want them.
However he has been careful never to do these kinds of things in public, and as far as the Beis Din and the community is concerned he is a completely upstanding member.
[I'm guessing that, depending on which aveirah, this kind of thing might be pretty common.]
Question: Is he a kosher witness? He knows what he has done, but no one else does beside the רבונו של עולם. The Beis Din will obviously accept him - they won't even listen if he would confess! If he is called as a witness to a Kiddushin does he need to decline if he cares about the couple, or is the only important thing what the Beis Din knows about him?
Maybe to illustrate the question I'll add something that I heard from a very big talmid chacham, which maybe should be a separate question. There's a she'elah on a piece of meat, and the Beis Din hears witnesses and rules it kosher. I have information that they don't that it is neveilah, and they wouldn't even believe me about it if I would have told them; say two witnesses said the opposite. In any case, I didn't say anything to anyone. Am I allowed to eat the meat?
This talmid chacham answered me briefly: "The Torah says you're not allowed to eat neveilah."

What's missing from the two questions you linked to that needs clarification? Also someone can respectfully decline the honor of being an eid rather than fleeing

Part of the routine for a Gett, by the way, is for the officiating rabbi to tell the witnesses to do teshuva for everything they may have done.

@יהושעק What is missing is the private obligation of the witness. They are discussing the law in the Shulchan Aruch that the Beis Din will continue to accept them. But he knows the truth; does that change anything כלפי שמיא?

@יהושעק "Also someone can respectfully decline" That seems to be changing the subject. Must he decline?

@Shalom Yes, I've heard that. Interesting, but... Is that an answer to my question? - I'm not sure what the answer is.

אין אדם נפסל בעבירה על פי עצמו אלא על פי עדים שיעידו עליו שאין אדם משים עצמו רשע: הגה (רמב"ם פכ"ב מטוען) ומ"מ אין עושין אותו עד לכתחלה כדלקמן סי' צ"ב סעיף ה' וכן אין נפסל על קול וחשד בעלמא כגון מי שחשוד על עריות שרגיל עם עריות ומתייחד עמהם וקול יוצא עליו כשר לכל עדות חוץ מלעדות אשה (טור ס"ט) וע' בדין החשודים בי"ד סי' קי"ט:
https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Choshen_Mishpat.34.25

@MichoelR The guy's a kosher witness. If he doesn't feel comfortable accepting the honor, he can decline. He doesn't need to resort to extreme measures like fleeing (which you suggested in your question)

@יהושעק@ אילפא "The guy's a kosher witness." "If he doesn't feel comfortable" The first statement seems to be ignoring the question here (is there a din כלפי שמיא that is not covered by what the Shulchan Aruch says), and the second suggestion I don't understand. Why should he not feel comfortable if he is kosher?

@אילפא, the Shulchan Aruch all of it is talking straight to the Beis Din.

Also kind of similar to the case of a Kohen's wife who was raped ch"v... we try really hard not to believe her so that they can stay together, but what about her obligation?

@Heshy Wow. I asked that talmid chacham that exact same question! "עיניה נתנה באחר". And he gave the same answer. He may be allowed, not knowing any better, but she is not allowed.

@MichoelR what the talmid chachum told you is heavily disputed, see the first teshuva in teshuvos ohr somayach, and many others, just the first siman somewhere is the easiest to remember. The basic gist is her issur is the byproduct of his practical issur.

@אילפא Yeah, I suggested that idea to him. It's pretty specific to that particular case, though, husband and wife.
